# Form Aligning issue | Bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

there is an issue with aliging of forms...

Here is what I am trying to do...
make a contact form on the left and to the right put the logo of the company..

So two divs of col-md-6 are made.. on the first div i am putting the form with class of "form-horizontal"

Hence I am arranging Form labels in "col-md-2" and form fields in "col-md-4"

Yet those form labels and fields are coming side-by-side... check image...

[image]

Here is the code...

```
<section id="contact">

   <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="background-image: url('images/head-background.png'); height: 100px; margin: 120px 0 10px 0;"><h2 style="margin-top:40px;">Contact Us</h2></div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div style="font-family:'MV Boli'; font-size: 20px;">

                <h4>Reach Us</h4>

                    <form class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-4">

                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control">

                            </div>



                            <label for="email" class="col-md-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>

                            <div class="col-md-4">

                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-Mail" class="form-control">

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </form>



            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">


            <img src="images/logo-vertical.png" class="img-thumbnail">


        </div>

 <section>
```

Please help people, on the verge of closing my first web-design project :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your need, Please try this, this is not your need please give me the clear input,

```
<section id="contact">

   <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="background-image: url('images/head-background.png'); height: 100px; margin: 120px 0 10px 0;"><h2 style="margin-top:40px;">Contact Us</h2></div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div style="font-family:'MV Boli'; font-size: 20px;">

                <h4>Reach Us</h4>

                    <form class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control">

                            </div>



                            <label for="email" class="col-md-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>

                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-Mail" class="form-control">

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </form>



            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">


            <img src="images/logo-vertical.png" class="img-thumbnail">


        </div>

 <section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make container col-md-12 for your form and image.Just make equal structure

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       form here
    </div>
    <div class-"col-md-6">
       // your image
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```